# Problems generating pdf from HTML with Pisa (Python)

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation, pisa

In my web app, writen in django, I met the need to convert an html
template in a pdf document. 
I decided to use Pisa and this is the incriminated code:

myview.py:

```
#view.py
...
import ho.pisa as pisa
import cStringIO as StringIO #pdf
...
@login_required 
def dettaglio_bolla(request, id=None, tipo=None):
        bolla = Bolla.objects.get(id = id)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id = bolla.destinatario.id)
    allegati = Allegato.objects.filter(bolla = bolla)
    paginator = Paginator(allegati, 2)
    try:
        pagina = int(request.GET.get('pagina','1'))
    except ValueError:
        pagina = 1
    try:
        pagina_allegati = paginator.page(pagina)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        pagina_allegati = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    response =  render_to_response("dettaglio_bolla.html",{'bolla':bolla,'cliente':cliente,'allegati': pagina_allegati})
    if tipo == ".pdf":
        result = StringIO.StringIO()
        pisa.CreatePDF(unicode(response.content,encoding="utf-8"), result)
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
    return response
```

The PDF is generated but all I get is a blank page. Did I miss something?
I checked the official tutorials but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried passing some simple static dummy content to `pisa.CreatePDF` to make sure that it creates a non-blank page? If so, most likely pisa chokes on your HTML input, try resetting your template and adding HTML sections one by one to identify the ones causing problems for pisa.

Comment: thanks for the answer, forgive me for the delay. I found the issue, it seems Pisa doesn't support the css positiong, I must rewrite the template with a table-layout